# Timeline broken

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Trying to view the timeline for [Thunderbird 3 "Reply to all", also replies to myself](https://superuser.com/questions/120241/thunderbird-3-reply-to-all-also-replies-to-myself) using the URI https://superuser.com/posts/120241/timeline fails with `Oops! Something Bad Happened!`. This doesn't happen with all questions, just this one.

Comment: Can reproduce the error! It's not just you! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, we have a fix for this checked in.